# Is it possible to get static property by class name?

Tags: java, android, class, reflection, static

For example, I need to get static property from one of my own classes Class1 or Class2 (property name is same for both classes) depend user action. I have only class name in String variable. How to get this property?

Certainly I can to do this:

```
InfoClass ic;
if(className.equals("Class1")) {
    ic=Class1.prop;
} else if(className.equals("Class2")) {
    ic=Class2.prop;
}
```

But that is not so fine solution, I think... Is there another way to implement this?

Comment: only if prop is static

Comment: @blackbelt, yes, prop is static.

Comment: then what`s the issue?

Comment: You can only do this using reflection, which is arguably even less fine than what you're doing. If you give some more information about your problem, it might be possible that there's a different way to do what you're doing that avoids either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, but as mentioned in the comments it's even less neat than your current solution.

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(qualifiedClassName);
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("prop");
ic = (InfoClass)field.get(null);
```

It's quite likely that there's a different way to do whatever it is you're doing in your app, which doesn't require reflection or a long list of conditionals; but I don't know enough about your problem to know what that is.

Answer (score 2):

Use reflection:

```
Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass").getDeclaredField("field").get(null);
```